# how to make i2c-core as module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, beagleboneblack

Hello I have beagleboneblack board and have kernel source code I want to make my i2c work as a module so for that, I have done some changes in .config file

```
#
# I2C support
#
CONFIG_I2C=m
```

and cross compile kernel

```
make dtbs zImage -j8 CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

But after compile successfully, CONFIG_I2C change from 'm' to 'y'
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Changing config files are a bit easier when doing  'make menuconfig'

Comment: yes but CONFIG_I2C change =m is not working how to solve this or guide me is i2c-core.ko file is possible or not ??

Comment: It could be your kernel is configured not to work with loadable models.  Anyhow, if this is the case, menuconfig would tell you.

Comment: So how to i forcefully work i2c core as module ?

Comment: Well, what I would do is work with menuconfig and see if you can set it there as a 'm'.  If your kernel is configured not to do, it will tell you why it wont do.

Comment: look https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/refs/tags/4-3/drivers/i2c/Kconfig there is clearly mention that "This I2C support can also be built as a module.  If so, the module
   will be called i2c-core." so how to do i ?

Comment: Don't do it by editing the .config file manually. Options depend on each other.

Comment: Can you help how I do that?

Comment: Use make menuconfig or something equivalent.

Comment: already do that only y/n option work (like  * I2C Device) i can't set I2C Device as 'm'

Comment: It means something else requires it built-in. Maybe to boot

Comment: Thank you for replay so how to i check ??

Comment: In make menuconfig, you can highlight a configuration option and use the 'Help' option to show information about the option. If the option has reverse dependencies (option is selected by other options), they will be shown as `Selected by [y]:`, `Selected by [m]:` and/or `Selected by [n]:` sections. In particular, a `Selected by [y]:` line shows which options are forcing the option to be selected as 'y'.

Comment: The first thing to check is that `CONFIG_MODULES=y` is selected. This appears as `[*] Enable loadable module support --->` in the top level menu of `make menuconfig`.

Comment: Thanks for replay i follow your information but I think we can't make i2c-core as a module so i2c-core.ko is not possible am i write or wrong ?

Comment: Ok thanks to correct me so can you help me how to do i ??